# How to get deeply nested class in requests

Tags: python, html, nested, python-requests

I have a script that uses requests to get html like this:
`r = session.get("https://www.instacart.com/store/wegmans/search_v3/horizon%201%25", headers=headers)`

and nested deep that webpage (about 26 layers deep) is the following element`<span>$5.59</span>`, which I want to scrape.  The next two elements up are `<span class=""></span>` and `<div class="item-price" style="flex: 1 1 0%;"></div>`, so my first thought was if I could find the "item-price" class, I could just go two layers further down, and I tried this code:

```
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
result = tree.xpath("//div[@class='item-price']")
```

but when I print result it just shows an empty list.  I've tried a number of other ways, and my theory is that the way I'm using xpath doesn't go deeper than the first layer of elements, because using an objective xpath where I specified body//div//etc sort of worked.

Is there a way I can recurse through all elements in this to find the "item-price" class, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instacart's pages are dynamically generated and `requests` doesn't execute javascript. That item list doesn't exist in the initial page load, only being added afterwards via javascript and ajax. (You can check this by right-clicking on the page and selecting "View source".)

The actual data is loaded from another dynamically generated url that looks something like:

```
https://www.instacart.com/v3/retailers/42/module_data/dynamic_item_lists/delivery_promotion?list_ref=unilevermainstream0719&origin_source_type=department&scores=&tracking.page_view_id=7f55bb7a-00bf-4fa8-ac48-fd9e0f10cc59&source=web&cache_key=f90e09-7286-f-5bb&per=30
```

Comment: so the solution is to use selenium or something to run the javascript and then scrape it once it loads?  Or are you suggesting I can use the generated url with requests somehow?

Comment: Trying to build your own urls will probably be more complex than it's worth. There seem to be a number of pieces that are tied to your session in some fashion so a bit of reverse engineering would be necessary. Using something like Selenium may be a way to get results faster.